# adding a cross-db trigger on the wp_users table results in registration not working anymore

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, database-trigger

I would like to duplicate some columns from the wordpress user table in table in a seperate database on the same mysql server.
Now if I add a trigger to the wp_user table in phpMyAdmin like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `WP_USER_2_FM_USER` 
AFTER INSERT 
ON `wp_users` 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO `mydb`.fm_users VALUES (null, NEW.ID, NEW.user_login)
```

I also tried:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.fm_users  
SET userid = NEW.ID,
    user_name=NEW.user.login;
```

I don't get any error messages from phpMyAdmin, but trying to register on the site afterwards does not work anymore. If I remove the trigger, registration works again.

I'm quite new to wordpress and mysql, so ... what is my mistake here?

PS: I'm using the Paid Member Subscriptions plugin, if that has any influence on this.

Comment: Show `mydb.fm_users` table structure. Specify `WP_USER_2_FM_USER.ID` and `WP_USER_2_FM_USER.user_login` datatypes. PS. 2nd query contains a typo in `user_name=NEW.user.login` - a point instead of underscore.

Comment: Thank you, your questions were all I needed to solve it. Tried to write a string into an integer field *facepalm*. Really should have seen that myself, but you how it is sometimes...